# Archive Node Syncing: Block Level and Block Hash Do Not Match

Tags: node, rpc, archive-node

Syncing an archive node from scratch. I noticed that the block level is inconsistent with the block hash.

```
# tail -n 2 /home/ubuntu/.tezos-node/tezos-node.log && tc rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head | jq '.header.level'
Aug 17 03:50:57 - main: validator-block : Block BLw3Kx7EfiSbMYAwH8nUyQLNc6aLiARZVmrrFVayQHcfxGaPJWU successfully validated
Aug 17 03:50:57 - main:                   Pushed: 2019-08-17T03:50:56-00:00, Treated: 2019-08-17T03:50:56-00:00, Completed: 2019-08-17T03:50:57-00:00(2019-08-17T03:50:57-00:00)
465454
```

[BLw3Kx7EfiSbMYAwH8nUyQLNc6aLiARZVmrrFVayQHcfxGaPJWU](https://tzscan.io/BLw3Kx7EfiSbMYAwH8nUyQLNc6aLiARZVmrrFVayQHcfxGaPJWU) is 465965, 511 blocks ahead of 465454

**Why would this happen?**

Comment: It should not happen. I think the rpc call was somehow delayed during ~511 blocks (or the log file is not the expected one). You should remove the "jq filter" to check if you are looking to the expected block information.

Comment: The log file was/is the only one, as specified in config.json. As far as removing jq, since the node was still syncing, I could see header.level changing very fast - it was the tip of the chain. Most importantly though, if you use `| grep level` instead of `jq`, you will get a dozen lines, but they all point to the same level. So it could have not been jq.

Comment: It seems that your are bootstrapping the chain: it explains the many head changes. Using `grep level` will also show you endorsements of the previous blocks. You should call `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/<expected_block_hash> | jq '.header.level'` instead of the last `head` to ensure that you are looking at the expected block.

Comment: my understanding is that if I am trying to find out how far I've synced I could look either at the log or at the head. maybe I have this wrong?

Comment: Of course. However, as a delay can occur between the two commands, it may explain this behavior. To track the bootstrap progress, you should rather use the `./tezos-client bootstrapped` command.

Comment: there was no visible delay though, and it would never move 511 blocks during an unnoticeable delay...